# Bullets Go Only Once forward Action Script 3.0

Tags: actionscript

I am new to Adobe Flash Action Script 3.0 but learning.

Geweer = the guy you are and kogel = bullet

I am having this code:

```
var geweer;  .

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,beweeg);
function beweeg(event:KeyboardEvent)

    { 
        switch(event.keyCode)
        {
            case 38:
            geweer.y = geweer.y -10;
            kogel.y = kogel.y -10;
            break;

            case 40:
            geweer.y = geweer.y +10;
            kogel.y = kogel.y +10;
            break;

            case 32: 
            kogel.x = kogel.x +20;
            break;
        }

            }
```

As you see. Case 32. When launched. The bullet will move from position only once(unless I press it multiple times). How can i make it to repeat(Without pressing multiple times)? And do it multiple times, to shoot multiple bullets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to write a game loop which handles all your logic at a regular time interval. A basic way to do this in actionscript is by subscribing to the ENTER_FRAME event.

Since your programming skills seem limited I suggest you first try to follow several tutorials on the subject you are attempting to program before asking such specific questions here.

A quick search seems to be able to help you. Check out 'PART 2 - Advanced detection' on [this page](http://www.newgrounds.com/bbs/topic/773868).

Comment: That worked, Thanks alot! I've got the following code now:

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
function enterFrameHandler(event:Event)

 {

kogel.x = kogel.x + 5

  }
.

Thank you.